# Why this simple for loop in batch doesn't work?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

```
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    set direc=%%d
    if /i not "%%d"=="data" (
        set subject=!direc!
        REM INTRO INFORMATIONS
        echo:
        echo *****
        echo Working With Subject: !subject!;          
        echo *****
        echo:

        echo ---- Running Step 1 ----
        echo:
        matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "addpath(genpath('%add1%'));addpath('%add2%');step1('%parentfolder%\!subject!\!subject!');exit;"
        rem Wait matlab to finish process
        :waitmatlab1
        echo Waiting for Matlab to finish process...
        timeout /t 10 /nobreak
        rem /I not case sensitive
        tasklist | find /I "matlab.exe"
        if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 (goto :waitmatlab1) 
        echo:
        echo *****
        echo Subject !subject! Finished.
        echo *****
        echo:
    )
)
```

My main directory has 3 folders but the following loop only run for the first (that has file inside for matlab) and command window pauses with "Subject 1 Finished" printed. I main to only jump to the next folder after executing the matlab task.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code - clearly all those echo/rem lines are not needed to demonstrate the issue. Additionally clarify which of the programs used in the script are exes and which are cmd/bat, ideally you write the example using some obvious/common exes and add sample for other cmd/bat files into the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - it's short enough that the problem is obvious; they've got a label inside of a `for` loop, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    set direc=%%d
    if /i not "%%d"=="data" (
        set subject=!direc!
        REM INTRO INFORMATIONS
        echo:
        echo *****
        echo Working With Subject: !subject!;          
        echo *****
        echo:

        echo ---- Running Step 1 ----
        echo:
        matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "addpath(genpath('%add1%'));addpath('%add2%');step1('%parentfolder%\!subject!\!subject!');exit;"
        rem Wait matlab to finish process
        CALL :waitmatlab1
        echo:
        echo *****
        echo Subject !subject! Finished.
        echo *****
        echo:
    )
)
GOTO :EOF

:waitmatlab1
echo Waiting for Matlab to finish process...
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
rem /I not case sensitive
tasklist | find /I "matlab.exe"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 (goto waitmatlab1)
goto :eof
```

Should fix your problem.

Notes: 
No labels are allowed within code blocks.

- This includes ::-style comments which are "broken" (unreachable) labels

Any `%var%` within a loop will be replaced by the value of that variable **when the loop is encountered** `%errorlevel%` included. Use `!errorlevel!` if delayed expansion is invoked, or the `if errorlevel n` syntax.

So - `CALL` the internal subroutine which executes a normal loop (and since it is no longer in a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of lines) then `%errorlevel%` will act as expected.

Note that `:` is not required in a `goto` - with the sole exception of **Goto :eof** where `:eof` is defined as being end-of-file.

Comment: `:` isn't required for a `goto`, but using one adds consistency with `call`s to subroutines